# How to come up with MOSFET equivalent of a tuned collector feedback oscillator?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, amplifier, analog, oscillator

I am trying to come up with a MOSFET equivalent version of the following tuned collector feedback oscillator. Primary objective to try with MOSFET is to improve the efficiency of oscillator.

[image]

But I am not sure how can I change the circuit when BJT is replaced with a MOSFET.

Kindly appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Why are you showing this circuit when clearly (following your previous question) this circuit has pitfalls. A circuit that has problems like this has nuances that are unwanted and anyone thinking about trying to fit a MOSFET to this is going to get bogged-down solving the basic circuit problems in order to choose a MOSFET that would work with similar performance.

Comment: @Andy, I was actually trying out with the modified circuit and had put the basic one here to make it simple. Thanks for pointing out and I changed the question by including the complete circuit.

Comment: [Link to previous question so as to understand performance criteria](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/359086/operation-of-tuned-collector-feedback-oscillator)

Comment: Insert the Nchannel (J)FET. Replace R2 (22K ohm) with potentiometer, 50K or 100K; initially set the pot to ZERO ohms. Now adjust the pot to increase the "gate" voltage. You may need more transconductance, so the next step is to reduce R3 to 100 ohms, and start increasing the gate voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both an NPN BJT and a N-channel MOSFET have the same sense of characteristic, increase the base/gate voltage and the current drawn through the collector/drain increases. However there are several differences.

The devices will be biassed slightly differently. A BJT has a fairly well defined 0.7v (ish) from base to emitter when the collector-emitter current is being controlled. The FET has a poorly defined gate-source threshhold voltage, which can easily vary by 2:1 for FETs of the same make, and do vary between types of FET. Threshhold voltages in the 1 to 3v range are to be expected. If you need accurate control of the drain current, then make your gate bias variable.

Although we normally think of a BJT as driven by its base current, for small signals we can also consider it to be base voltage driven, and define its \$g_m\$. A FET will tend to have a lower \$g_m\$ than a BJT, so allowance for this must be made in your choice of feedback components.

Comment: Thanks, @Neil_UK, I I tried by changing the 2N3904 to IRF530, but it doesn't oscillate as it does for BJT. which parameter should I tune in order to make it work?

Comment: You should also add that in many cases it's better to use a Depletion mode NFet for this application as it does not require biasing. Since it draws significant current when turned on it is self starting, and biases itself to a mode C operation automatically.

Comment: @Pojj You will need to change the biasing arrangement to get the same [gm](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee105/fa98/lectures_fall_98/091898_lecture11.pdf) that the BJT had. Also you should not use a power MOSFET like the IRF530, instead an RF MOSFET.

Comment: @Pojj Whoa, IRF530 is a power fet, which means humungeous interlectrode capacitances, which will totally swamp your 40pF. If you're going to replace a 100mA BJT, use a 100mA FET, much more similar. As Mr Creasy says, better to use a depletion FET, not because it 'doesn't require biassing', but because the bias voltage can be zero, and it self biasses through the voltage drop on the source resistor to ground. Oh, and they tend to be small devices, more like a 100mA NPN.

Comment: Thank all for the comments. I am back to the basics, and trying to understand the operation of amplifiers and oscillaters. @Neil_UK, could you suggest a suitable FET model, so that I can simulate in LTspice?

Comment: 2N3819 is the 'BC108' of FETs, or was when I were a lad.