# Whats the equation to calculate the Vo-w and Vp amplitude of this Wien Bridge oscillator?

Tags: voltage, oscillator, ltspice, voltage-measurement, wien-bridge

[image]Im trying to find the equation to the amplitude of this wien bridge, if you could help me that would be awesome

Comment: What wien bridge?

Comment: fixed the image problem!

Comment: [Somewhat related question; different oscillator type, same problem with amplitude stability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/359086/operation-of-tuned-collector-feedback-oscillator?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

There is not an equation as you mean it. In the case of your circuit, the non-inverting gain will be about 3.2, so the amplitude of the output will increase without limit - until it hits a limit.

In this case,that limit is set by the op amp output stage and the power supplies. If you look at the data sheet (you *have* looked at the data sheet, right?) you'll see that for +/- 10 volt supplies you'll get a maximum of about 8 1/2 volts, so let's say that the output stage can drive to within 1.5 volts of the supply. This means that, given your +/- 9 volt supplies, at an output swing of about +/- 7.5 volts the output will start clipping, and the output waveform will stabilize at that level. Due to the clipping, the purity of the sine wave will be much less than it would be if you used a dedicated amplitude control. Hewlett-Packard got their start selling Wien Bridge audio oscillators which used an incandescent lamp as the control element, and this produced very respectable distortion numbers.

Comment: Place a 22kohm resistor in series with back-back diodes. Install that series network across the R4.

Comment: To stabilize the amplitude (before hard-limiting) you can - alternatively - place such a series network also across R3 (soft-limiting effect). In this case, it is somewhat easier to roughly calculate the resulting amplitude of the oscillator output.