# Do not understand why current flows in undamped oscillator circuit, and getting troubles in practice

Tags: transistors, oscillator, antenna, capacitance, inductance

I want to make my own antenna, so I started to make a generator. I found scheme below (only without a **K** key in the bottom) in internet, and it seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

[image]

There PNP transistor, as you can see, assumes that + should be on emitter and - on base (don't know how it will be correctly in English version), but there actually + on the emitter and + on the base - no potential difference, transistor is locked. I understand that the answer is probably inductance. Honestly I am not good in inductance knowledge - I know that it creates a self induction EMF, but I'm confused.

But okay, if it is correct, and I just do not understand why, hence it should work in real. I need a 60 Mhz frequency, so I've calculated that **L** should be 1.3 µHn, and **C** - 5.1 pF, so I bought the following components:

- [Transistor 2N3906(rus. documentation)](https://www.radiolibrary.ru/reference/transistor-imp/2n3906.html)
- [Capacitor 5R1 5.1 pF](https://www.escomponents.com/capacitor-value-conversion-table/)
- Inductance 1.1 µHn,  ±20%
- As voltage source I used 5V DC phone charger.

I built the circuit, and nothing happens. I changed circuit little to test  as shown below - lamp doesn't light.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, the very FIRST thing you're doing wrong is misinterpreting the diagram. Those are not two inductors - they are a single transformer. So buying a 1.1 uH inductor will not remotely help.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, I actually bought 2 inductors, and just put them together, it's wrong?

Comment: Oh my sweet Lord. Look, Artur, I don't know where to begin. You need to do a lot more reading before you try this. Start with finding out what "transformer" means.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, come on, I know what do transformers do, and how do they work. There are to separated solenoids; there are current in one of them; current produces an electromagnetic induction on the second solenoid, so there happens e.m.f; transformers can increase or decrease voltage. Is these knowledge enough for You, to answer my question?

Comment: If you continue to think that two separate inductors will form a usable transformer, then there is nothing I can tell you. Have fun.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, no, sure, the isolation does absorb paticulary magnetic field of inductor, plus I don't know that inductor actually is a solenoid, but thought it will work. Maybe You know some simple generator circuits?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You picked a circuit that does not show any biasing arrangement for the transistor nor shows polarity information on the transformer windings. Likely is that you found the circuit on some website that is trying to explain the functionality of an oscillator and, to make it easier on the learner, they omitted bias arrangements and transformer winding polarity in an attempt to make things clearer (never really a good idea).

Given that I see numbers pointing to various points on the circuit it looks like me that the diagram originates from a patent document and these are notoriously light on information that isn't relevant to the patent.

Comment: Then, probably You can give me a normal circuit?

Comment: @Artur how does that follow? I will find you a webpage that has loads of oscillators but you need to also do some research.

Comment: [Colpitts oscillator images from internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=colpitts+oscillator&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikjef8m4bdAhURYxoKHXJqAFEQ_AUICigB&biw=1196&bih=902)

Comment: [Common collector colpitts oscillator](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&biw=1196&bih=902&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=AEGAW6j8MMrYaJeEoKAL&q=common+collector+colpitts+oscillator&oq=common+collector+colpitts+oscillator&gs_l=img.3..0i24k1l2.84094.87784.0.89000.17.17.0.0.0.0.122.1274.16j1.17.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.8.634...0i7i30k1j0i8i7i30k1.0.KGaxMrxbBbA) this is my preferred type for around 60 MHz but there are hartley oscillators and also pierce oscillators.

Comment: Well, okay, but this is just one of the solutions. What about related in my question? What's wrong there?

Comment: My answer explained what you did wrong and told you that the circuit was missing components and information that in their absense would prevent the oscillator working.

Comment: [Here is a link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/359086/operation-of-tuned-collector-feedback-oscillator?rq=1) to an oscillator circuit similar to yours that I helped get working for a SE user. It ran at 2 MHz but that was only through choice of LC components. Note the BJT biasing arrangements and careful application of positive feedback to avoid excessive distortion (really important when testing an antenna).

Comment: What does BJT means?

Comment: @Artur: BJT means Bipolar Junction Transistor - an NPN or PNP transistor.

Comment: I love it when a discussion on oscillators results in, "What does BJT means?" It kind of tells you where things are really at.

Comment: @jonk, I just don't know English terms, descriptions, relax

Comment: @Artur I'm quite relaxed. Just kibitzing. If you haven't taken the time to look it up before asking, it goes to one issue. If you have, and don't understand it, it goes to another issue. That's all. Don't worry about me. I'm fine.